# Difference between systemd software watchdog and "normal" process monitoring

Tags: process, monitoring, systemd, watchdog

I've tried out 2 systemd unit configurations:

progA.service

```
[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/opt/progA
WatchdogSec=10s
```

progB.service

```
[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/opt/progB
Restart=always
RestartSec=10
```

The effect in 2 cases is similar: whenever the program killed/crashes/exits, it is restarted after 10s. To my understanding, using watchdog has advantage only if a specific thread/loop inside the program need to be monitored. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the watchdog will detect "liveness" above and beyond the `Restart` directive, which only detects "deadness".

In order to [avoid being killed by the watchdog](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#WatchdogSec=), your service must actively call `sd_notify`. Imagine if something bad happens that doesn't quite kill your service, like a deadlock. The process would not be killed with a `Restart` directive, but it would fail to send the `sd_notify` and would be restarted by the watchdog (as long as the checkups are being sent on the same thread that is deadlocked).

Comment: Thank you. That confirms my thought about it.

Comment: Done. Thanks for asking. It's just new 2 me.